# Will move to search engine friendly URLs help or hurt an already good search engine ranking?

Tags: seo, cms

Hi I'm moving a mostly static site with some dynamic asp.net pages into a new CMS. The CMS uses SEO friendly URLs while the old site used dynamic URLs ending in .aspx. The client is worried that this might somehow change their great Search Engine Rankings especially since the URLs will be a bit different now. I'm trying my best to keep the new URLs as close as possible to the originals but I'm wondering if this move will help or hurt with their SEO. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URLs are SEO friendly, then I guess that they will not be a problem in the ranking. However, from my experience switching the CMS has always some unpredictable impact on the ranking. The search engines themselves have posted some guidelines for webmasters what to look out for. Some are here:

- [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en)
- [Yahoo](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/search/higher-website-rank-sln2216.html)
- [Bing](http://bing.com/webmaster/help/webmaster-guidelines-30fba23a)

They all **mention** the URL but it is just one aspect of many. In my opinion, more important is the question if the new CMS is SEO friendlier than the old system. If not, it could well result in a worse ranking. However, without further info I would say no, the URL itself should not have a bad impact on the rating (If the URLs are still SEO friendly of course. It also helps if they have a connection to the content of the page.).

Comment: I'll hook you up buddy!! ... Done!